# Recipe for solving linear discrete-time model for which N(t) is influenced by N(u) and N(v) u<t, v<t.

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

For solving linear discrete time model of the form
$$N_{t+1}=pN_{t}+c$$

(when saying solving I mean that $N_{t}$ is expressed only in function of $p$, $c$ and the initial conditions)

one can first solve for the equilibrium:
$$N_{equi}=\frac{c}{1-p}$$

Then define a variable `d` as the distance of the system from the equilibrium: 
$$D_{t}=N_{t}-N_{equi}$$

The recursion equation for `D` is $D_{t+1}=pD_{t}$ because $$D_{t+1}=n_{t+1}-N_{equi}=pN_{t}+c-N_{equi}$$

Replacing $N_{t}$ with $D_{t}-N_{equi}$ gives 
$$D_{t+1}=pD_{t}+pN_{equi}+c-N_{equi}$$

Therefore, the general solution for `D` is
$$D_{t}=p^tD_{0}$$

So, the general solution for `N`is
$$N_{t}=p^t(N_{0}-N_{equi})+N_{equi}$$
which also equals
$$N_{t}=p^tc_{0}+(1-p^t)N_{equi}$$

**Does it make sense?**

**What is the recipe for solving a model of the form:**
$$N_{t}=pN_{t-1}+qN_{t-T}+c$$

T can take any integer values in the range [0;t]

The answer is maybe given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471408/general-solution-to-a-growth-equation) by Ron Gordon but I could not really understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\displaystyle{N_{t} = p\,N_{t - 1} + q\,N_{t - T} + c}$

Define
$\displaystyle{%
\xi_{t} = N_{t} - {c \over 1 - p -q}
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
\xi_{t} = p\,\xi_{t - 1} + q\,\xi_{t - T}
}$.
Try solutions like $\mu^{t}$ which leads to the characteristic equation
$$
\mu^{T} - p\,\mu^{T - 1} - q = 0
$$

You get $T$ solutions: $\mu_{1},\mu_{2}\ldots\mu_{T}$. Your general solution looks like

$$
N_{t}
=
\sum_{n = 1}^{T}A_{n}\,\mu_{n}^{t} + {c \over 1 - p - q}
$$